# laravel Model Undefined index after add static function boot()

Tags: php, laravel, model

i add this styntax to model :

```
public static function boot()
{
   if(Auth::user()){
        parent::boot();
        static::saving(function ($model) {
            $model->school_id = Auth::user()->school_id;
        });
        
        static::addGlobalScope('school_id', function (Builder $builder) {
            $builder->where('school_id', Auth::user()->school_id);
        });
     } 
}
```

goes well on the web, but not in API, error :

> ErrorException: Undefined index: App\SmStudent in file
> /home/simsmar/public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php
> on line 241

.

Laravel Framework 5.8.37

when i delete "if(Auth::user())" and only "public static function
boot()" it's still same error

Comment: May be you are logged in,  on API but not logged in,  on web. Are you checking the authenticate user with  `if(Auth::user())`?  then you can check like that `if(Auth::check())`

Comment: but when i delete "if(Auth::user())" and only "public static function boot()" it's still same error

Comment: Can you please current post your current laravle version ? So I can help you.

Comment: Laravel Framework 5.8.37

Comment: Hi, what is the line that causes the exception?

Answer (score 14):

Finnaly, i found the solution

just give

parent::boot();

in first line of statif function